# How to Pass Custom Values like Username or E-mail into SurveyMonkey

Tags: django, python-3.x, surveymonkey

Working on Integrating a SurveyMonkey Survey into a website.
How do I pass Username or Email of a Logged in User to the Survey?
I am using an Embedded Survey. Any Documentation Links would be welcome.

Also, Can I get real-time Response from SurveyMonkey to get the results after a user has finished the taking survey? I have a Paid Plan.

Using Django to build the website.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this today with the SurveyMonkey embed code. Create a [weblink collector](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Web-Link-Collector) instead and insert the URL with [custom variables](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) into and iframe in your HTML.

Example:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/BGNV5MY?username=[username_value]&email=[email_value]"></iframe>
```

For realtime response notifications, use [webhooks](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks) to get notified and then fetch the [response details](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-id-details).