# SurveyMonkey custom variables in embedded survey

Tags: asp.net, api, surveymonkey

I'm trying to use a SurveyMonkey embedded survey in our website.
I know we can pass custom variables such as username in the url using a Web Link Collector.
However I don't see any articles about passing custom variables using an embedded survey.
Is it even possible?

Or maybe someone could guide me how to achieve my goal with SurveyMonkey?
Here is the scenario I would like to achieve.

1. We would like to popup a survey when a user logs in.
2. We would like to get back which survey and when it was complete for each user from SurveyMonkey.
3. We would like to store the data in the database we get back and determine to popup the same survey when a user logs back in or not.
4. Repeat this every year.

Can SurveyMonkey do this?

Comment: We also need this same functionality, would appreciate if you update if you find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to the SurveyMonkey help desk, and I was told that it is not possible to use custom variables in their embedded survey.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue and struggled for a bit. For anyone facing this issue, the acceptable work around I was able to implement was answered here:

[How to Pass Custom Values like Username or E-mail into SurveyMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809781/how-to-pass-custom-values-like-username-or-e-mail-into-surveymonkey)

Basically, instead of creating an embed survey collector, you create a weblink collector. You then create an `iframe` and set the `src` to be the given link which will accept your custom variable.

For example:
`<iframe src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/ABCDEFG?CustomVariable=mycustvar"></iframe>`

For fellow angular developers, if you are doing this and dynamically setting the `[src]`, you will also need to use the `DomSanitizer` to bypass security, though this may make your app susceptible to XSS attacks.